# Date add/subtract in cassandra/spark query

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a scenario where I need to join multiple tables and identify if the date + another integer column is greater than another date column.

```
Select case when (manufacturedate + LeadTime < DueDate) then numericvalue ((DueDate - manufacturepdate) + 1) else PartSource.EffLeadTime)
```

Is there a way to handle it in spark sql?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Could you elaborate the question more. What about _case when_ is not working?

Comment: does the integer represent a number of days? Also, is it Scala or pyspark?

Answer (score 2):

I tried with sqlcontext, there is a date_add('date',integer). date_add() is hive functionality and it works for cassandra context too.

```
cc.sql("select date_add(current_date(),1) from table").show
```

Thanks
Aravinth

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DataFrame with your data, you are using Scala and the "another integer" represents a number of days, one way to do it is the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._    

val numericvalue = 1
val column = when( 
  datediff(col("DueDate"), col("manufacturedate")) > col("LeadTime"), lit(numericvalue)
).otherwise(col("PartSource.EffLeadTime"))
val result = df.withColumn("newVal", column)
```

The desired value will be in a new column called "newVal".

Comment: Thanks and yes, I'm using scala and the integer represent some integer value, we can assume that as number of days. I don't a DataFrame for this, I just use the plain query and which I get the below error,

    cannot resolve '(17038 + 5)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(17038 + 5)' (date and int)

I guess, I would join the tables and make it as DataFrame and apply your suggestion.

Comment: @ashK how are you running this query? via sqlContext.sql? If so, you can try `datediff(DueDate, manufacturedate) > LeadTime`

Comment: We use NoSQL and I run it through Cassandra context. I can try in sqlContext.

Comment: @ashK I'm not sure you will be able to try with sqlContext, because I think you are querying you Cassandra table directly (therefore with Cassandra syntax). I think you have two options: 1) bring your data to a DataFrame and try my initial suggestion or 2) save your table as a Spark SQL temp table and use sqlContext.sql (with Spark SQL syntax), then you will be able to use datediff

Comment: Yes, I'm trying via dataframe, I get an error saying recursive value col needs type on col("duedate) and I suppose LeadTime should col("leadtime") rite?

Comment: @ashK sure, I'm sorry I didn't have time to test the code. I edited it now.